# How to include select query for javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jvectormap

I have Developed Jvector map.Now working fine.its showing details well.Now i  want show country details from database.its all file javascript.Finally i have decided and create php database file

database.php

```
<?php
Content-Type: application/json;
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "mydatabase";
$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
    or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('Could not select database');
  $query = "SELECT countryId,country,pdogcoregion,comments,ccl,category FROM countrydetails WHERE Country='Canada';
";    
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
        $all_recs = array();
        while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $all_recs[] = $line;
        }

echo json_encode($all_recs);
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

i have created Simple database in mysql workbench.
1   Canada  North America   None    Giovanni Facciponte Approved
2   India   ROW None    Ritika Balaji   Require Approvel

now display data all country look like here i post india country details 
case  'India' :

label.html("**Country**:&nbsp  India
**Category**:&nbsp  Requires Approval
**PDP GCO Region**:&nbsp  ROW
**Comments**:&nbsp  This country is complex 
**CCL**:&nbsp Ritika Bajaj");
    break;

here ajax code:

```
<script>
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(function(){
          var $ = jQuery;
          $('#focus-single').click(function(){
            $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {region: 'AU', animate: true});
          });
          $('#focus-multiple').click(function(){
            $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {regions: ['AU', 'JP'], animate: true});
          });
          $('#focus-coords').click(function(){
            $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {scale: 7, lat: 35, lng: 33, animate: true});
          });
          $('#focus-init').click(function(){
            $('#map1').vectorMap('set', 'focus', {scale: 1, x: 0.5, y: 0.5, animate: true});
          });

          $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "database.php",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{country : country}",
                success: function(data){
                    sr = data;
                }
        });
```

but i want this details from database? how i will do please help me ?

Comment: you might want to use ajax

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As it is, it's rather hard to understand what exactly are you looking to solve, what have you tried, and how is it not working. Please see the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for info on how to ask a good question.

Comment: alex have paste my ajax code please take look